# Cannot start services on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, service, systemctl

Suddenly, I cannot start services on my VPS(CentOS 7). For example,

```
service httpd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
Failed to start httpd.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status httpd.service' for details.
```

This is probably because the domain name I used as the host name has expired. I do not know the logic behind the service command. I start httpd, why does it invoke polkit service? The polkit service is also dead and cannot be started. The "service polkit status -l" command shows a message:

```
Lost the name org.freedesktop.PolcyKit1 - exiting
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: what does `systemctl start httpd` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sudo`

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start httpd
```

or login as `root`

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start httpd
```

in order to start and stop services.

Comment: I am also having this problem, however I still get the same error message even when as root. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @rnoodle Click the Ask Question button.